# Prove that $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ for any non-negative integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction

$2^{3^n}$ must be 2 mod 3, which it must be since it is 0 mod 2. However, for certain cases, this does not hold, and I have trouble showing why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use *induction*: for the the inductive step, note that $2^{3^{n+1}}=\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}\bigr)^3$, and rewrite
\begin{align}
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n+1}}+1&=\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}+1\bigr)^3-3\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}\bigr)^2-3\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}\bigr)=\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}+1\bigr)^3-3\cdot2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}+1)\\
&=\bigl(2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}+1\bigr)\Bigl[\bigl(
2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}+1\bigr)^2-3\cdot2^{3^{\scriptstyle n}}\Bigr].
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

By [lifting the exponent lemma](http://euclid.ucc.ie/mathenr/IMOTraining/2016AugustCamp/lifting-exponent-lemmaRob.pdf), we have
$$
\nu_3\left(2^{3^n}+1\right)=\nu_3\left(2^{3^n}-(-1)^{3^n}\right)=\nu_3(2+1)+\nu_3(3^n)=1+n,
$$
where $\nu_3(k)$ is the $3$-adic valuation of $k$.